# How to click elements that have generated id's if I don't know what the ID will be in Selenium

Tags: javascript, selenium, testing, selenium-chromedriver

Say I have some HTML mark-up as such:

```
    <select id="select_titleOfSelect-1212_01" name="titleOfSelect-1212" 
        <option value="ONE"></option>
        <option value="TWO"></option>
        <option value="THREE"></option>
    </select>
```

Multiple of these select elements can be generated dynamically
in which the number after `titleOfSelect` can always be different. 
Also the "01" will increment by 1 if there is more than one select generated on the same page.

I have been able to click on these using this:

`.click('select[id^="titleOfSelect-"] option[value='ONE']')`

How can I click on the 2nd, 3rd, so on.. select element on the page if there is more than one?

I'm using Javascript with Selenium

Answer (score 1):

You don't search for the element based on its ID if the ID is randomly generated. You'll have to use an XPath or CSS selector and get creative.

Here's how I would click on the options:

```
// option 1
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select/option[@value='ONE']")).click();

// option two
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select/option[@value='TWO']")).click();

// etc..
```

Or, if you don't want to use `value`, you can use the index:

```
// click first option
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select/option[1]")).click();

// click second option
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select/option[2]")).click();

// click third option
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select/option[2]")).click();
```

If there are multiple `select` elements on the page, you can try to do a `contains` query on the title:

```
//select[contains(@title, 'titleOfSelect')]/option[1]
```

Comment: Makes sense and thank you. In regards to "If there are multiple selects" part of your answer. How can I select the 2nd or 3rd select element using that contains query. Looks like that would just select the first one on the page?

Comment: You can change the index of `option[1]` to the index of the item you want to select -- to select 2nd option, you'd use `//select[contains(@title, 'titleOfSelect')]/option[2]`, and for the third, you would use `//select[contains(@title, 'titleOfSelect')]/option[3]`. If your options have the `value` filled in, you can also use `//select[contains(@title, 'titleOfSelect')]/option[@value='ONE']`, `[@value='TWO']`, etc..

Comment: What I mean is if I have two select elements that are identical

Comment: Apologies, I misunderstood your question. you can use the index of the select element as well, as such: `//select[1]/option[1]` or `select[2]/option[1]`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `:nth-of-type()` to pick which SELECT you get, e.g.

```
select:nth-of-type(2) option[value="TWO"]
```

would select the OPTION that contains the value 'TWO' in the second SELECT

Comment: Oddly I get undefined

Comment: I'd have to see the code. I ran this locator on a local copy of your HTML and it worked just fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the `findElements` method to find the locator `id^="titleOfSelect-"`. This will return `ReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement>` which you can convert to a list and then target whatever `index` you want to target.